# rubymine code completion of model object

Tags: rubymine, code-completion

Our rails project involves two databases: Postgres and MS sql server.

In the one database case :

When a variable holds a model object, RubyMine suggests suitable code completion with created dynamic queries, e.g. find_by_name, find_by_phone ....

But in model like :

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

establish_connection :sqlacc

self.table_name = 'ACC_CODE'

...

the model object from Customer did not get code completion with created dynamic queries, i.e. find_by_code ...

Would somebody know how to get this work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a **known limitation** in Rubymine, unfortunately. See [these](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-6530) [two](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-7734) open issues and, if you can, vote for them.